# Type 'Debb' is not known on line 1 in source list

Tags: apt

I want to install chrome and enter the source list

when doing `sudo apt-get update` there is an error as follows:

```
E: Type 'Debb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

how do I fix it?

Comment: Delete the repository you are trying to add and [follow these directions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-linux-12-xx-13-xx/)

Comment: Edit the file and insert 'deb' instead of 'debb'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
sudo find /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list* -type f -exec sed -i 's/Debb/deb/g' {} \;
```

It replace Deeb with deb in google.list and google.list.save (if exists) , and then run this command `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: you can shorten that to just `sudo sed -i -e 's/Debb/deb/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` as we know the file in the error message and so we really do not need find.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I Wanted to replace the string in .list and .list.save

Comment: `sed ... /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list*` or similar

Comment: **find: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list*': No such file or directory** this is I got msg what am I do for it?

Answer (score 3):

I think there might be a typo in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` file.

Look into line 1 of that file carefully, `Debb` could be a typo of `deb`

Or you can follow the [Google Linux Software Repositories](http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/) page to do command-line installation, 
or even download the .deb file directly.

But no matter what, don't forget to fix this issue since it will interfere `apt`, remove the list you created could also do the trick.